# laravel 5.5 change logout route without compromising the security

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am attempting to change the routing redirect after the logout has been requested. I would like to maintain the security implemented by the artisan:auth command.

Answer (score 1):

On the LoginController you can override the method logout, like this:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/WhereverYouWantTo');
}
```

Comment: override means that you add that method to the controller and therefore the parent's logout method (the framework's located at Illuminate\Foundation\Auth::logout ) will not be used.